Sculpting brushes
Everytime I try to sculpt all of the brushes become giant and pixelated,I made sure my shapes are decent size and changed the brush sizes to a smaller one but nothing works. For example with the draw tool it doesn’t create a line, it creates a light crease and that’s all it does as well the size always stays giant.

hello, maybe you have activated the Dyntopo option?

Does your object have enough vertices? (Sculpting moves existing vertices)
